# Do not start sessions for anonymous users

Tags: spring-boot, session

How can I disable sessions for anonymous users in spring boot 2.0?

My current configuration:

```
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/password/forgot/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/password/reset/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/manage/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers( "/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

When I open the login page, there is still a session created:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the session is being automatically created by Spring Security. That behavior can be disabled by setting `create-session` to `never`. This means Spring Security will not attempt to automatically create a session.

```
<http create-session="never">
[...]
</http>
```

Some more details here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to do 3 things:

1. Add `http.anonymous.disable()` to my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.
2. Also add `http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)`. I don't know why, but this **DOES** create sessions for my authenticated users, even though the docs say that it will never create sessions for you.
3. Deleted all my cookies before testing. I discovered that if you made a request with an old session cookie, the server would use said cookie to create a new session, ignoring completely the `SessionCreationPolicy` we just set.

Answer (score 0):

try adding "anonymous.disable()" after http in FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .anonymous.disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/password/forgot/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/password/reset/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/manage/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers( "/favicon.ico").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .permitAll();
}
```

Enjoyy!